# .htaccess rewrite issue - what am I missing?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

All I want to do is a very simple redirect so that `mypage.html` is displayed in the browser, but `index.php?s=1` is the page that is served up.

What am I missing here?

`redirect 301  /mypage.html index.php?s=1`
- this redirects the whole page as expected

`RewriteRule ^/index.php?s=1$ mypage.html [R=301,L]`
- this returns a 404 error when I access `mypage.html`

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to redirect FROM mypage.html TO index.php?s=1?

If that is the case, you have your RewriteRule in the wrong order. It redirects you to mypage.html if you try to access index.php?s=1.

This shoud do the trick (no guarantees. I did not test the rule, just switched the filenames in your rule):

```
RewriteRule ^mypage.html$ /index.php?s=1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

`mypage.html` is displayed in the browser, but `index.php?s=1` is the page that is served up.

If this is **not** a redirect you want to do (i.e. the URL in the client browser *doesn't change*) then you just have to make a rwriterule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^mypage\.html$ /index.php?s=1 [QSA,L]
```

Nothing more.

And now, if you want the user **not** to be able to type `index.php?s=1` then add this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/index\.php$ mypage.html [R=301,L]
```

So, all in all:

```
RewriteRule ^mypage\.html$ /index.php?s=1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/index\.php$ mypage.html [R=301,L]
```

Hope this helps